# Facebook Open Graph requires me to use debugger all the time

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When I write a post and try to share it on facebook the open graph info is wrong. I have to use the debugger every time. Is there something I can do to make this more automatted?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update

Comment: @CBroe The issue I'm having isn't updating form a change but a new page is being scraped incorrectly. The open graph tags are present but the first time we share the wrong image is used. I have to run the debugger a few times till facebook picks up the image.

Comment: You can trigger an initial scrape after you published a new article, using the API mentioned there. But specifying the image dimensions should also be able to solve this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29697938/1427878

Comment: @CBroe - so it looks like I can call `https://graph.facebook.com/?id=[my url encoded]&scrape=true` to force the scrape via the api. Using v2.6 I'll just need to include the access token as well. Correct?